# setting a default sort for a GridView

Tags: vb.net

I removed the "order by" clause in my SQL Stored Procedure and I'm trying to apply the same default sort inside my GridView.

Please note that I don't want the users to be able to sort the GridView, I just want the data sorted a certain way when presenting the GridView.

Here is my GridView:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvMonsters" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"></asp:GridView>
```

And here is how I'm trying to sort:

```
Dim dt As DataTable = getTableChoiceLinks()
dt.populateFromSql
With gvMonsters
    .DataSource = dt
        .DataBind()
        .Sort("monsterID", SortDirection.Ascending)
End With
```

But when I run it, I keep getting this error:

> The GridView 'gvMonsters' fired event Sorting which wasn't handled.

Am I using the wrong sort property?

Thanks!

Comment: Sorting belongs into the database

Comment: I had read somewhere that moving sorting from the Stored Procedure to the Gridview can speed up the databinding of a gridview. I don't know, I just read that. Thanks! @TimSchmelter

Comment: That's  nonsense. If the query is too slow optimize it, f.e. by adding  appropriate indexes.

Comment: Oh ok, well I'll move it back to the Stored Procedure.  Thanks!